# Tiny MCE - Displaying stored, formatted code

Tags: php, mysql, tinymce

I am new to Tiny MCE and love it, but I don't have it configured properly somehow. I have a form in PHP. There is a textarea where I am using Tiny MCE. I submit the new record or change and the formatted code is stored in the MySQL DB properly. Copied from the DB field directly:

```
<span style="color:#e03e2d;"><strong>Red text</strong></span>
```

If I just render it on a page without using Tiny MCE it looks perfect. On my update page, when the data is pulled into the textarea field that is formatted with Tiny MCE, the formatted code is broken as it is rendered. When I look at the source in the field in Tiny MCE it looks like this even though the DB record is correct:

```
<strong>Red text</strong>"&gt;
```

I don't know why it strips off the span tags and adds that right arrow. When I render the record on a page, all I am doing it this:

```
<textarea name="notes" value="<?= $results[0]['notes'] ?>"></textarea>
```

It looks like I need to tweak the Tiny MCE config so that when I pull in existing formatted text from the DB, it honors all the formatting, but I am not sure what to change.

```
<script>
    tinymce.init({
        forced_root_block : false,
        selector: "textarea",
        menubar: false,
        plugins: "link code lists",
        toolbar: 'undo redo | styleselect | forecolor | bold italic | numlist bullist | alignleft aligncenter alignright alignjustify | outdent indent | link | code',
        setup: function (editor) {
            editor.on('change', function () {
                editor.save();
            });
        }
    });
</script>
```

If I submit as is, the messed-up record gets stored in the DB. So even if I am not updating that field, I have to correct the formatting that was rendered. Pain in the backside.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: May not be related, but [textarea does not have a value attribute](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/textarea). The value goes in between the tags.

Comment: Agh! That was it. I had copied and pasted code from other text inputs and totally missed that. Problem solved. Feel free to post that as the answer.

Answer (score 0):

Textarea values belong between the tags, since [textarea does not have a value attribute](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/textarea). It's messing up because when the value is added, it looks like

```
<textarea name="notes" value="<span style="color:#e03e2d;"><strong>Red text</strong></span>"></textarea>
```

Which of course messes up the quotes and is not correct. Instead, move the value between the tags:

```
<textarea name="notes"><?= $results[0]['notes'] ?></textarea>
```